Problems with globally defined Java and Javascript functions after update
I recently updated Karate from 1.2.0 and Java 8 to 1.4.1 and Java 11. Previously I had defined Javascript Functions and Java Types globally in karate-config.js, which were used frequently.
config.isValidDateTime = read('classpath:validators/datetime-validator.js')
config.TimestampObject = Java.type('utils.Timestamp')

For the Java Types, this no longer seems to work, I cannot execute the methods. When I call e.g.
* set userProfile.firstName = UserMockHelper.getRandomFirstName();

I receive the error message:
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "UserMockHelper" is not defined

The Javascript function can still be executed directly in the scenario, but it does not work within a JSON validation, such as
And match response.docs[0] contains { timestamp: "#? isValidDateTime(_)" }

I now always get the following error message:
TypeError: execute on {} failed due to: Message not supported.


this is very late so I'll have to point you to the upgrade guide and also search around for others who may have run into the same problem: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - I suggest you provide a way to replicate if you really want a solution sooner: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

You examples are a little confusing as you mention setup for timestamp in your config, but the error you show is for UserMockHelper.  You also seem to be mixing js and java setups in your post.
NOTE:  It would be better to post each issue in separate tickets.  I will address the java setups, and ask that the js issue be posted in a separate ticket.
For the java type issue, you can try this setup.  We set the following in our karate.config
  config.commonUtils = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.CommonUtils')
  config.dateUtils = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.DateTime')
  config.fileUtils = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.FileUtils')
  config.rndUtils = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.RandomUtils')

These point to various java files that contain common functions used across numerous tests.
sample java file for DateTime
package commonutilhelpers;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateTime {
    public static String customCalendar(String fromJs, Integer Year, Integer Month, Integer Day, Integer Hour,
            Integer Minute, Integer Second) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fromJs);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, Year);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, Month);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Day);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, Hour);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Minute);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, Second);
        String dateAfter = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        return dateAfter;
    }
}

Usage within a feature
* def deferredUntilDate = dateUtils.customCalendarUTC("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", 0,0,7,0,0,0)

